# The essence of the Addition operator within arithmetic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, arithmetic, education

How do I characterize the addition operator, without defining its properties using set theory or the peano axioms, so that someone with special needs could understand and apply it in the context of arithmetic and at most algebra? What is the definition of the addition operator in the simple context of algebra and arithmetic, and how is it understood?

Comment: Using lengths and areas you can geometrically motivate addition and multiplication. That's the intuition I prefer to use.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I find the definition on the [ Wikipedia addition diambiguiation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_(disambiguation)) to be pretty intuitive, as it encompasses both the geometric and set interpretations.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what type of definition you’re looking for? For example, does $$a + (-a)=0$$ count as a property?

Comment: @Knight, A synonymous description for the process, properties and uses of addition would be nice! Yeah, something like a+(−a)=0 could be part of the description, but it kinda has to be understandable by a student with special needs

Comment: @lmn32 What’s the level of the students whom you’re targeting? Are they getting their first introduction to arithmetic?

Comment: @Imn32.May I ask what sort of special needs this question concerns?

Comment: @Knight Yeah, I'm trying to introduce the + operator to someone with special needs. They haven't ever added before, and they're just starting out with math if that helps with the context. I'm just trying to introduce the + operator with a sufficient "depth" if you will, so that the person understands and doesn't only memorize the addition algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to write what I understood from [Prof. Herbert Gross's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Gross) teachings and innovation.

The addition operator operates on numbers, so a good knowledge of numbers can give us some insights. If we follow this [PowerPoint](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=B46D0C79F461D8EC!120) by Prof. Gross, we have something very interesting to look at

> In a similar way, $3$ inches is a $\color{grey}{quantity}$ in which the $\color{red}{adjective}$ is $\color{red}{3}$ and the $\color{blue}{noun}$ (unit) is $\color{blue}{inches}$ As quantities, $2$ fingers is *not* the same as $3$ inches. However, as $\color{red}{adjectives}$, the "$\color{red}{3}$" in "$3$ fingers" means the same thing as the $\color{red}{3}$ in "$3$ inches".

And from this [presentation](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=B46D0C79F461D8EC!174) we have

[image]

If the students are asked to put two tiles, they will probably do this
[image]
[image]
And if they are asked to put those two tiles along with three more tiles, they will probably do this

$$ {\Huge \color{blue}{\blacksquare\blacksquare \qquad \blacksquare \blacksquare \blacksquare}} $$

> And they will count those tiles as "one, two, three, four ,five", and thus know that there are five $\color{blue}{tiles}$.

[image]

[image]

$$
\begin{aligned}
{\Large \mathbf{\text{How to apply it in Algebra}}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Let's say we have $3~\color{red}{apples}$ and $2~\color{blue}{oranges}$ and if I ask you how many **fruits** do I have, you will answer $5$. So, what you have basically done is that you did the following translation
$$
3~\color{red}{apples} \rightarrow 3 ~\mathbf{fruits} \\
2 ~\color{blue}{oranges} \rightarrow 2~\mathbf{fruits}
$$
And then you added "3 fruits" and "2 fruits" in the same way as we added the tiles above.

Now, let's say we have any noun $x$, such that $3x$ means we have $3$ of those $x$(in the same way as $3$ fingers, or $3$ inches) and $2x$ means we have $2$ of those. If we say that we are given $3x$ and $2x$ then how many $x$ do I have in total? We can surely apply that tiles example once again to see things clearly, because it is stated that $x$ is any noun. Let's visualize $x$ by some strange looking figure and draw $3$ and $2$ of them

[image]
We again find, by counting, that we $5$ of $x$'s or $5x$.

---

As the question strictly doesn't allow Set Theory's or Peano's Axiom (works of [Gottlob Frege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottlob_Frege), [Bertrand Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Russell)) definition of addition so I wouldn't touch on that and end my answer here.

Comment: Yeah this is great, I was thinking about introducing it this way. Easy to model with number tiles too! I'd give you the point for this question, but I'm kinda waiting for some other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

So after some thought, I've come to the conclusion that a definition of addition in the context of only algebra and arithmetic is impossible, as there are multiple uses of addition even in these two disciplines. Addition should therefor be introduced as a man made, hence useful calculation, "way", or "method" of calculation that is very useful in making collections bigger, or lengths longer.  What matters when introducing this operation is emphasizing its uses in most situations imaginable.

For sets and such, addition could be characterized by using toys or number blocks, where a collection of toys consists of two separate collections of toys, where the joining represents addition. This is effective in allowing students to learn that addition of toys is equivalent to combining toys [image: Singapore math number bonds]
[image: number bonds vs addition]

and a number line be used to show addition as the combination of lengths

[image: number line addition]

The number line approach could be introduced after students become familiar with "tactile" addition, to further the idea that addition can be generalized to the concept of length, which is more abstract than quantity.